# Insert a document between 2 pages of another

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm wondering if I can do the following:

1. Find a bookmark within a document
2. Identify the page number this bookmark is on
3. Insert another document before the identified page

My code so far:

```
Sub InsertDoc

    Dim MasterDoc As Document
    Dim bookmarkRng As Range
    Dim pageNo As Long

    Set MasterDoc = Documents.Open("Master.docx")

    Set bookmarkRng = MasterDoc.Bookmarks("TheBookmark").Range

    pageNo = bookmarkRng.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)

    '1.This is where I need to specify to insert before/after the found page, not sure how
    MasterDoc.InsertFile FileName:="AnotherDoc.docx"

    '2.Is it possible to use this syntax instead and specify before/after insertion of a whole file?
    MasterDoc.Bookmarks("TheBookmark").Range.InsertFile FileName:="AnotherDoc.docx"

    MasterDoc.Save
    MasterDoc.Close
    Set MasterDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best not to think in terms of pages, which ironically is an ill defined concept in Word. But if you're inserting material, you have to insert it at specific location anyhow. Since you find a range for the bookmark, and it looks like you want to insert after the bookmark, use the following:

```
MasterDoc.Bookmarks("TheBookmark").Range.InsertAfter "XXX"
```

Also, you could remove *bookmarkRng* and *pageNo*, then, unless you need them later for some reason.